# Adding a space in a String after a certain character(VB Code)

Tags: string, vb.net, textbox, space

Hello everyone.

```
    Dim txt1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text) / 100
    Dim txt2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim txt3 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text)
    Dim txtResult As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox4.Text)

    Dim result As Double = txt1 * txt2 * txt3
    TextBox4.Text = result
```

As you can see I get my result depending on what the user types in. So I have to add a space after a certain character. Textbox14.text(0) <--- after this do I want my space. It's so that after the value is higher than 999 it should type out 1 000 and not 1000. Thank you very much for any useful help, I've truly looked everywhere, I just can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You talking about group separator. [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use `.ToString()` method and define group separator in the format.

```
TextBox4.Text = result.ToString("0,0.000")
```

Different separators will be used based on the local system's language/region settings.

You can define your custome separator manually

```
var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
var numberInfo = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
numberInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

TextBox4.Text = result.ToString("0,0.000", numberInfo)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man, it was actually just that easy! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want every 3 chars a space, right ?
Like 1 000 000 ? 
try this :

```
Dim result As String, str As String, ret As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr As Char()
'your text to space 
result = "10000000"
'reverte so we start with the end
result = StrReverse(result)
i = 0
ret = ""
' make a char array which each char is an own array element
arr = result.Take(result.Length).ToArray
'iterate through all elements
For Each str In arr
    ' skip the first element . 
    ' only add a space every 3 elements 
    If (i <> 0) And (i Mod 3 = 0) Then
        ret = ret + " "
    End If
    ret = ret + str
    i = i + 1
Next
' revers again the output
ret = StrReverse(ret)
MsgBox(ret)
```